# Does it make sense to perform Domain Adaptation before Transfer Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

Suppose I would like to do extractive question answering on scientific literature. I'm interested in using BERT which was pretrained on Wiki and Bookcorpus. I see two routes here:

**1**. Fine-tune BERT on scientific literature (specifically abstracts) using the masked language modeling task, then replacing the head and fine-tuning with an extraction question answering scientific literature dataset (SQuAD like).

**2**. Go straight to fine-tuning on the downstream task of extractive question answering.

I know in both cases there would be transfer learning and domain-adaptation. But I believe I would get better results if I allowed the base model of BERT to learn and understand the vocabulary, patterns, etc. of scientific literature. In other words place more emphasis on domain-adaptation before doing anything else. Does this make sense or is this overkill?